# Rendering (error) with display: table-cell;

Tags: html, css, tablecell

Im currently working on a website. The Header of the HTML file looks like this:

```
<div id="page">
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="redsquare">&nbsp;</a>
        <div class="head-wrapper">
            <!-- some more -->
        </div>
        <div class="flags-container">
            <!-- some more -->
        </div>
    </header>
```

The css for this html section looks like this:

```
#page {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 223px;
    background: #F0F0F0 url("../resources/header-background.png") repeat-x;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-row;
    clear: both;
}

header > a.redsquare {
    background-image: url("../resources/logo-figure.png");
    float: left;
    height: 223px;
    width: 240px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

header > .head-wrapper {
    height: 223px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

header > .flags-container {
    width: 110px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 83px;
    float: right;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    clear: both;
}
```

All the elements are on their place, but between the `redsquare` and the `head-wrapper` and between the `head-wrapper` and the `flags-container` there is a small line (shown on the picture below).

[image]

My question is, how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you provide a JsFiddle Link please !

Comment: can I add images to jsfiddle?

Comment: My advice is not to use display 'table' or 'table-cell' for positioning. CSS and browser development are moving towards allowing code to have as much semantic value as possible. So you should use the previous values for tabular data, not for positiong. Use the `flex` model or absolute positioning to achieve your goal, as they are more reliable cross-browser.

Comment: Okay I ended up making a fiddle. @HotPizzaBox, JSFiddle isn't for images, instead you can paste your html, css and javascript into an editor that can be shared and updated online, allowing the users here to physically see you test your code. It's a win for everyone involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the markup and css you posted and made a fiddle, because the default behavior of a table is to separate cells with a border you need to override it by adding

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

to you #page element.

[image]

Quickly tested this in IE and Chrome, [fiddle can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2cqe4j5/)

**However** I do strongly agree with other comments in that you shouldn't be using tables, or emulating tables for design reasons, instead I suggest using the same html structure but rather than

```
display: table-cell;
```

try using

```
display: inline-block;
```

This will result in the same 'column' effect but is less tragic. Tables are tragic.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your effort. I tried the idea with the flex layout. The only thing I am concerned about is the browser compatibility. But as I can see on the web, only IE 8 & 9 does not support is.